# Kivy Spinner action when same value is selected

Tags: python

I have successfully implemented Kivy spinner as I have shown below, am making a popup when a value is selected, works very well the first time, however if I click on the same value in the spinner a second time, the method is not called the second time....My imagination is that listener is bound to text change..Is there a way to perform event even when the same value is selected consecutively, in which case the text won't have changed?

Initialize

```py
self.payment_spinner = self.ids.payment_spinner
self.payment_spinner.values = ['Cash', 'Card']
self.payment_spinner.bind(text=self.on_purchase_spinner_select)
```

The Method

```py
def on_purchase_spinner_select(self, spinner, text):
   today = date.today()
   print(today)
```

Comment: This question was answered right [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634772/how-to-select-kivy-old-value-for-the-spinner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this functionality , all you have to do is instead of using the on_text method on the spinner, you can call on the Buttons that are opened by the spinner. Here is a working example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    on_release: app.spinner_selected(self.text)

RelativeLayout:
    Spinner:
        text: 'Choose One'
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        option_cls: Factory.get('MySpinnerOption')
        values: ['1', '2', '3']
        # on_text: app.spinner_selected(self.text)   # not needed
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def spinner_selected(self, text):   # whatever method you want to run
        print('spinner selected:', text)

TestApp().run()
```