# How to select kivy old value for the spinner

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, spinner, kivy-language

Kivy documentation states that "Touching the spinner displays a dropdown menu with all the other available values from which the user can select a new one." Is there any workaround to tell if it is an old value a user selected in order to perform the same action? I am really stuck with this, please help me out.

Comment: Save the value selected so you can compare it next time the `Spinner` is touched.

Comment: Hey @JohnAnderson, this solution isn't working because the onselect method is only called if the text changes, therefore when you choose the same method, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `on_text` or `on_select`, you can use the `Buttons` that make up the `DropDown` to trigger whatever method you want to run. That way, it doesn't matter whether the same `Button` is selected or not. Here is a simple example of that approach:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    on_release: app.spinner_selected(self.text)

RelativeLayout:
    Spinner:
        text: 'Choose One'
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        option_cls: Factory.get('MySpinnerOption')
        values: ['1', '2', '3']
        # on_text: app.spinner_selected(self.text)   # not needed
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def spinner_selected(self, text):   # whatever method you want to run
        print('spinner selected:', text)

TestApp().run()
```

The above code sets the `on_release` of the `Buttons` in the `DropDown` of the `Spinner` to the method that you would normally assign using `'on_text`. Now, that method will be called whenever one of the `Buttons` is released.

Comment: Thanks alot @John Anderson I had struggled with this for days